# angular filter is returning an object. How to avoid that?

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, nested-loops

I have a JSON file and it's format is as shown below. Some values are just strings, while others are objects with key value pairs.

`[{
        "question": "How many names do you have?",
        "answer": "1) Mark, 2) Ram, 3) Sam, 6) Paul, 7) Bob"
    }, {
    "question": "What are your habits?",
    "answer": [{
      "id": 1,
      "value": "Coding"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "Gaming"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "Sleeping"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "value": "Enjoying good food"
    }]
  }, {
        "question": "What are you like?",
        "answer": "I'm a simple person who minds my own business."
    },
    {
        "question": "What habit do you like most?",
        "answer": "I like coding the most."
    }]`

And my output on the html is [as shown here (click to see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHfKV.png) which is what I want. I used nested ng-repeat to show the proper values which are objects. 

But when I filter those results, the output displayed is a json object and not a simple list, which is what I don't want.

Where is the mistake I'm doing here while filtering and how can I avoid it?

Please help. 
[Full working code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kyYK3ewlJOf51zUDDjlM?p=preview)

Comment: First time when you click on question it returns okay and your condition : <div ng-if="isArray(counselingJson[$index].answer)"> is executed and returns true and afer searching from input second condition "<div ng-if="isString(counselingJson[$index].answer)">" is true, Plz check this condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the index of your questions changes when you filter. Instead of using `counselingJson[$index].answer`, use `qAndA.answer`. Working plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/cTCzUyS89b7KAh3RnAlM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions for your code, please do semicolon after your json array value;

```
 {
        "question": "What habit do you like most?",
        "answer": "I like coding the most."
    }];
```

and for conditions you should check if like following:

```
<div ng-if="isString(qAndA.answer)">
    {{qAndA.answer}}
</div>
<div ng-if="isArray(qAndA.answer)">
   <ul ng-repeat="a in counselingJson[$index].answer">
      <li><strong>{{a.id}})</strong> {{a.value}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```